# Componentization of large unreadable SQL query makes it too slow but lack of central definitions of concepts proves dangerous

Tags: php, sql, refactoring, structure

I am struggling to work out how to write code that is both fast enough for the task at hand but that is also well structured so as to be readable and maintainable in the future.

The task is to generate a sales report in php which draws on data from an SQL database. This report returns thousands of rows each of which represents a sale. Many of the columns of the report must be computed at the time of generating the report as their values are not stored in the database. I have written one large SQL query that generates the report in one go very quickly.

My problem is that this creates code duplication and in addition it would be very hard for someone to understand the SQL code in terms of system entities. For example I have a function in my function library that returns the amount of money received towards a sale. It calls the following piece of SQL to do so.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount_received
FROM transactions
WHERE
    tran_status = 'Success' AND
    booking_id = $booking_id
```

When creating the report it is too slow to call this function once for each individual sale after I get the thousands of sales from the database. So instead I JOIN the following to my SELECT statement so the sales arrive from the database with an amount_received column.

```
SELECT booking_id, SUM(amount) AS amount_received
FROM transactions
WHERE tran_status = 'Success'
GROUP BY booking_id
```

I have done this with many different system concepts when writing this report and I know that it is dangerous to have such key concepts defined in more than one place and that even I struggle to read my massive SQL query. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is my first ever question so sorry if I have done anything wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Show full query and exec full query in pma with leading string "EXPLAIN ";

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an N+1 Query problem. A report is going to be a separate entity, no matter what you do, and will require additional framework. Consider creating set-driven alternatives to your single object queries, and plug them into multi-object sets, be it arrays, or whatever your choice structure is. Make it flexible enough to take in a bunch of IDs, then pass those IDs to your various components to get data back. Then you can iterate the enormous sets to calculate what you need. Note: this approach is very memory-heavy because you're storing a lot of data before touching it, outputting it, etc. I recommend returning resultsets instead of populated arrays - the SQL server will have that memory in use anyway.

This way, you get your definitions, you have a faster (but still not optimal) solution, and then reports are objects that are about how you run which results sets and the composition of the report to page.

Comment: Great answer, I don't have a good enough 'reputation' to 'vote up' but thank you. It seems obvious now you say it but it just didn't click with me until you pointed it out.